# SurveyMonkey API: export a csv or excel file of respondents?

Tags: surveymonkey

Is it possible to export a csv or excel file through the SurveyMonkey API?  Or is it necessary to page through the json get_responses and compile that list manually?

Since you can export excel and csv reports through in the SurveyMonkey interface, it would be nice to have that functionality in the API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The full list of available APIs is available on the developer page here: https://developer.surveymonkey.com/

There is no export function for any files, the only methods supported return JSON data (as you said: via get_responses).

It is an often requested feature and it has been noted there is a lot of demand for it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Do you have a sense on where this feature might land in your roadmap?  Just wondering if there is a chance this comes out in the next couple months or if it is a feature further along down the line.

Comment: It's expected further down the line - I can't give a firm date, but very likely longer than two months from now.  It is something we'd like to tackle sooner rather than later though.

Comment: @openwonk I'm not involved with this anymore, but at this point I would assume such functionality is not on the cards.  Maybe check out this integration?  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/surveymonkey/caipcojfoolgojgbomkmeokjmfecahha?hl=en